# Nodejs - async - parallel - limit callback is not a function

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I got this error after running the code below. Can anyone help?

> TypeError: callback is not a function

```
api_call_arr.push(async function(callback) {
  let api_result = await apiHelper.makeAPI('post', api_data);
  if (api_result.Errors !== undefined) {
    console.log('success 1');
  } else {
    console.log('error 1');
  }
  callback(null, true);
});
async.parallelLimit(api_call_arr, 5, function(err, data) {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the async operator before your function [turns it into a promise](https://medium.com/@matansokolovsky/es7-async-await-pitfalls-d24331388a70).
I [guess](https://github.com/caolan/async/issues/1524) that the async lib is not handling this yet.
You can remove the async keyword and do something like

```
 apiHelper.makeAPI(...)
        .then((result) => callback(null, result.Errors !== undefined))
        .catch((err) => callback(err, false)))
```